# Auto-numbering components in LTspice

Tags: schematics, ltspice

I'd like to re-number the components of my LTspice simulation from left to right and top to bottom to make the schematic more presentable. For example, in the circuit below, I'd like R44 to be R1, R50 to be R2, R28 to be R3, and R27 to be R4 (and similarly for the other components). I know the combination Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R re-numbers all the components, but I think it does it in the order in which components were placed, not in the left to right, top to bottom order I'm looking for. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only way to do it, presently. If you want to achieve your goal, the only method would be to place them in the order you want, or to do the renumbering yourself. You can try to write to the creator of the program (Help > About). Try to be short and concise, but there are really no guarantees you'll get the change. In fact -- and without trying to sound negative -- I am 99% sure it won't be implemented.